# HTML, JS: visual multi-level, drag-and-drop menu editor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I'm building a cms based on laravel and need some help on building a visual (Wordpress-like) multi-level menu editor with drag-and-drop feature. I've set up a model of a menu item for this:

```
class BeryliumItem extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('id', 'type', 'category', 'title', 'href', 'parent', 'menuID');

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Then the editor view retrieves the items like this:

```
@php
    $ct = 0;
@endphp
@foreach (App\Extensions\Berylium\Models\BeryliumItem::where('menuID', $model->id) as $key => $item)
    @php
    $ct++;
    @endphp
    <!-- here should go the editor -->
@endforeach
@if($ct == 0)
    <div class="col s12 center text-center"><h5>{{ trans("Berylium::berylium.empty") }}</h5></div>
@endif
```

It should be then possible to retrieve from the editor the order of items, to check if each item has a parent (or is on the first level of the menu). I can use jquery (and/or any other javascript libraries) and, if it's helpful, the app has materializecss@0.98 included. Could you give me some suggestions on how to implement such an editor (with some code please)?

Comment: Question is far too broad and there are lots of drag/drop tree scripts readily available on the web you can start from

Comment: Thanks, could you give a link to any?

Comment: Not hard to find in web search